# Is using object-like macros a good way to define global variables?

Tags: c, macros, global-variables, constants, c-preprocessor

I've been told by my teacher that the preprocessor command ***#define*** is the way to go to declare a global variable. Basically I use the [object-like macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros)

```
#define x 3
```

to declare ***x*** as a global variable. Now, I was used to do something like that to define these kind of variables and I have been recommended to not do that anymore :

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int x = 3;

int main(void){...};
```

As far as I can see (let's take in consideration that I'm new to C and programming in general), the two ways of declaring the global variables are pratically the same, if we talk about how the program works.
Assume that I have a code like thath :

```
y = x * 3;
```

this code will compile and run without any problem at all, both using `#define x 3` and `const int x = 3;`. Now, I'm surely missing something here, but I really can't see a difference! Can someone gently show me what's the point of the question?

Comment: `#define x 3` does *not* create a global variable.

Comment: @immibis What is what it does, then?

Comment: It defines an object-like macro. Object-like macros are different from global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` was used to create a constant, not a variable, but now it's frowned upon for that purpose. `#define x 3` is a preprocessor directive that basically means "replace `x` with `3` everywhere in the source file". It's like a search and replace in a code editor with the "match whole word" and "case-sensitive" options on.

`const`, on the other hand, creates a legitimate identifier with an address and scope and everything. It can be used just like a variable, even with the `&` (address of) operator. It just can't be assigned to.

Comment: So, is this something more related to the style of the code?

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Imagine somewhere else you have a for loop: `for(int x = 5; x < 10; x++) printf("%d\n", x);` Guess what will happen if you use the #define?

Comment: It's more than that. Say I wrote `#define x rand()`. Everywhere I use `x` in my code, it gets replaced by `rand()` and produces a new random number. If instead I use `const int x = rand()`, it will only compute `rand()` once and every time I use `x`, I'll get the same number.

Comment: @immibis You are right, but you can avoid this error in a simple way, this is not a real problem hence

Comment: @ClaudioCortese What's the simple way?

Comment: @immibis Do not use int x, instead int another_name

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Well yeah, but that's pretty impractical if you already have 2000 different local variables called x.

Comment: @immibis Well, that's why I would use #define, you have a value that is repeated more than one, not only in the main, I think that it's simpler changing the name of a single variable instead of replacing the value in all the code

Comment: @ClaudioCortese But you could use `const int x = 3;` and then there'd be no problem with existing local variables called x.

Comment: @immibis That's the point.. if I can use this, why should I use #define instead? Am I not seeing something that my teacher does? Is there something more than an int x that would break your code? Maybe optimisation-wise? Is it just a style thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference for #define and Const value for this small piece of code. But if you are coding for a performance critical code , consider #define because it makes your value global, It is pre-processed by the compiler While Const have normal lookup.
Advantage it that #define automatically replaces every occurence of the name. 
And disadvantage is that it conflicts if you have same name used many times in your code.

Comment: That "lookup" will be optimized away by any better-than-totally-horrible compiler.

Comment: Perhaps this is why my teacher said this is the best way to declare a global variable

Comment: @JohnSensebe Wait, did I miss something? Is using const int more optimised than #define?

Comment: No, but a decent compiler will make `const` as efficient as a `#define`. It used to be said that `const` was slower for the reason in the answer, but today that is rarely the case. Plus, with `const` there is type checking and debugging can be easier.